# unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR but no TypeChecker errors (Hacklang)

Tags: hacklang

```
<?hh //strict
```

---

```
foreach ($list as $id) {
    $items = new DestinationsByCountry($id);
    $remapped = $items->byKey('destination_id')->map($stringed ==> (int) $stringed);
    $this->ids->addAll($remapped);
}
```

---

```
foreach ($list as $id) {
    $this->ids->addAll(
        // ******* error line below *******
        new DestinationsByCountry($id)
            ->byKey('destination_id')
            ->map($stringed ==> (int) $stringed)
    );
}
```

Both is OK for the typecheker, but the second cause fatal error

> Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'

Comment: In PHP this is illegal syntax, and can be worked around with `(new DestinationsByCountry($id))->byKey ...` - not sure if this works in hacklang?

Comment: Thanks, that's my fault. This works in hacklang. I was just confused with the typechecker says nothing on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above, you need parenthesis around `(new DestinationsByCountry($id))`, in both PHP and in Hack syntax.

The reason the typechecker doesn't complain is because [it doesn't typecheck code at toplevel](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/unsupported/top-level). If this had been inside a function or method, I expect the typechecker would have found the error. If this code was in fact inside a function or method, please do [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues).

Comment: There's already an issue for this, though the example should be updated to wrap the code in a function (hh_client still doesn't report an error): https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/6809

Comment: The example is inside a function of a class in a strict mode